# Can an equilibrium be reached when there is an excess amount of one reactant over the other reactant?

Tags: physical-chemistry, equilibrium

For example, consider a net reaction between ferrous nitrate and potassium thiocyanate:

$$\ce{Fe^3+(aq) + SCN-(aq) <=> (SCN)^2+(aq)}$$

Can an equilibrium be reached if there is a much greater excess amount of one reactant over the other:

$$[\ce{SCN-_{(aq)}}] \ll [\ce{Fe^3+_{(aq)}}],$$

or

$$[\ce{SCN-_{(aq)}}] \gg [\ce{Fe^3+_{(aq)}}]$$?

If not, is it okay to consider it as an irreversible reaction in these cases?

Comment: [Equilibrium constant when adding more of a reactant](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/29581)

Comment: Does exist a solution for $$K=\frac{x }{ (a-x)(b-x)}$$ for the real $K \gt 0$ and  real $a \gg b \gt x \gt 0$? Yes, it does. // You must mean ferric/iron(III) nitrate, not ferrous/iron(II) nitrate.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever the initial and the final amounts of reactants and products, the formation of $\ce{[Fe(SCN)]^{2+}}$ ion is always an equilibrium. If a strong complexing solution, like EDTA, is added to the red solution containing $\ce{[Fe(SCN)]^{2+}}$ ion, whatever the relative amounts of the remaining $\ce{Fe^{3+}}$ and $\ce{SCN-}$ ions, the red color disappears, which means the formation reaction is reversible.

Comment: Not necessarily reversible the complex is destroyed. Reversibility requires the same mechanism in both directions.

Comment: The reversible reaction is $\ce{Fe^{3+} + SCN- <-> [Fe(SCN)]^{2+}}$. It does not imply that the formation of the complex of $\ce{Fe}$ with EDTA is reversible.